# Are remote and local branches identical?

Tags: git, github, branch

Assume the following situation:

1. Developer pulls remote branch named X
2. Git automatically creates a local copy of X
3. Developer removes remote X
4. Developer pushes local X to the repo

The question is: Is the new remote branch the same branch it was before deleting? Do other developers need to something to commit to this branch again?

Comment: Got through most of your English... but what's "smth"?  I think the answer to your question is yes, this branch is the same.  When you push the branch to remote it should tell you that it's creating a new branch.

Comment: I think "smth" is "something". Anyway, edited to read that way, because I can imagine others are going to stumble on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing this, the remote branch will be unchanged. Hence, the other developers do not need to do change anything and can simply continue working on this branch:

(even though, to be honest, I do not see a scenario where this would be useful)